# how do session window merge multi stream in event time?

Tags: apache-flink

introduce of session window from flink office's

[image]

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#session-windows
...a session window operator creates a new window for each arriving record and merges windows together if they are closer to each other than the defined gap. In order to be mergeable, a session window operator requires a merging Trigger and a merging Window Function,...

I have a question about session window  merge, in case of as follow

[image]

in this case, two-stream into one operator, user1 arrives before than user2, and time interval of the first window of user1 with the first window of user2 more than GAP,
session window how merge the first window of user1 and user2?

which case as follows in event time? The above time of the image is event time.

case 1:

session window First: w1 of user1

session window Second ： w2 of user1, w1 of user2

case 2:

session window First: w1 of user1, w1 of user2

session window Second: w2 of user2

Answer (score 1):

The figure that you copied from the documentation is showing keyed session windows, where the windowing is being applied independently to the streams from different users. With keyed session windows, windows for different keys (i.e., different users) will never be merged.

In other words, session windows do not "merge multi-stream". Either the windowing is not keyed, in which case there is a single stream, or the windowing is key-partitioned, in which case the sessions are determined independently for each key.

This pattern holds throughout Flink's APIs. Allowing keyed streams to be independently processed is crucial for scalability.

Comment: You're welcome. It would be nice if you were to accept my answer, or indicate how it could be improved.